# Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception; SpringBoot and Vaadin

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, javabeans

I am going to be upfront, I am a newb in Java, especially with SpringBoot. I've been aping the Vaadin CRM tutorial application with minor custormization for my needs.
When I try to login, it throws the following error, which I cannot figure out, so again, I am just going to copypaste the entire stacktrace:

---

There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the exception message 'Error creating bean with name 'listView' defined in file [C:\Users\nikol\Desktop\vaadin-crm\vaadin-crm\target\classes\com\vaadin\tutorial\crm\UI\views\list\ListView.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.ListView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property type 'java.lang.Integer' doesn't match the field type 'java.lang.String'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.'

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'listView' defined in file [C:\Users\nikol\Desktop\vaadin-crm\vaadin-crm\target\classes\com\vaadin\tutorial\crm\UI\views\list\ListView.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.ListView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property type 'java.lang.Integer' doesn't match the field type 'java.lang.String'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:106)
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:160)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:137)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:136)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:525)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:505)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:222)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:249)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:220)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:186)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.initializeUIWithRouter(BootstrapHandler.java:1532)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1525)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:475)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1547)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.ListView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property type 'java.lang.Integer' doesn't match the field type 'java.lang.String'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property type 'java.lang.Integer' doesn't match the field type 'java.lang.String'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.bindProperty(Binder.java:2859)
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.lambda$null$26(Binder.java:2759)
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.handleProperty(Binder.java:2948)
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.lambda$bindInstanceFields$27(Binder.java:2757)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:563)
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.bindInstanceFields(Binder.java:2761)
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.LivreForm.<init>(LivreForm.java:44)
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212)
    ... 122 more
```

---

ListView as mentioned in the stacktrace is aas follows:

---

```
package com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Key;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.value.ValueChangeMode;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Campus;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Livre;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Stock;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.service.CampusService;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.service.LivreService;

import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.LivreForm;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.MainLayout;

/**
 * A sample Vaadin view class.
 * <p>
 * To implement a Vaadin view just extend any Vaadin component and
 * use @Route annotation to announce it in a URL as a Spring managed
 * bean.
 * Use the @PWA annotation make the application installable on phones,
 * tablets and some desktop browsers.
 * <p>
 * A new instance of this class is created for every new user and every
 * browser tab/window.
 */
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Livres | ENI Ecole Informatique")
public class ListView extends VerticalLayout {
    LivreService livreService;
    Grid<Livre> grid = new Grid<>(Livre.class);
    TextField filterText = new TextField();
    LivreForm form1;
    
    
  
    
    public ListView(LivreService livreService, CampusService campusService) {
            this.livreService = livreService;
            addClassName("list-view"); 
            setSizeFull(); 
            configureGrid(); 

            
            
            form1 = new LivreForm(campusService.findAll());
            form1.addListener(LivreForm.SaveEvent.class, this::saveLivre); 
            form1.addListener(LivreForm.DeleteEvent.class, this::deleteLivre); 
            form1.addListener(LivreForm.CloseEvent.class, e -> closeEditor());
            add(grid); 
            add(filterText, grid, form1);

            Div content = new Div(grid, form1); 
            content.addClassName("content");
            content.setSizeFull();
            add(getToolbar(), content); 
            updateList();
            closeEditor();
            }
   
        private void configureGrid() {
            grid.addClassName("livre-grid");
            grid.setSizeFull();
            grid.removeColumnByKey("campus");
            grid.removeColumnByKey("stock");
            grid.setColumns("titreLivre", "description", "auteur", "refeni", "isbn", "categorie", "status"); 
            grid.addColumn(livre -> { 
                Campus campus = livre.getCampus();
                return campus == null ? "-" : campus.getNomCampus();
            }).setHeader("Campus");
            grid.addColumn(livre -> { 
                Stock stock = livre.getStock();
                return stock == null ? "-" : stock.getQuantiteStock();
            }).setHeader("Stock");
            
            grid.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true));
            grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(event -> 
            editLivre(event.getValue()));

        }
        
        public void editLivre(Livre livre) { 
            if (livre == null) {
                closeEditor();
            } else {
                form1.setLivre(livre);
                form1.setVisible(true);
                addClassName("editing");
            }
        }
        
        private void saveLivre(LivreForm.SaveEvent event) {
            livreService.save(event.getLivre());
            updateList();
            closeEditor();
        }

        private void deleteLivre(LivreForm.DeleteEvent event) {
            livreService.delete(event.getLivre());
            updateList();
            closeEditor();
        }
        
        private void closeEditor() {
            form1.setLivre(null);
            form1.setVisible(false);
            removeClassName("editing");
        }
        
        private HorizontalLayout getToolbar() {
            filterText.setPlaceholder("Filtrer par titre ou auteur..."); 
            filterText.setClearButtonVisible(true); 
            filterText.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY); 
            filterText.addValueChangeListener(e -> updateList()); 
            
            Button addLivreButton = new Button("Ajouter livre");
            addLivreButton.addClickListener(click -> addLivre()); 

            HorizontalLayout toolbar = new HorizontalLayout(filterText, addLivreButton); 
            toolbar.addClassName("toolbar");
            return toolbar;
        }
        
        void addLivre() {
            grid.asSingleSelect().clear(); 
            editLivre(new Livre()); 
        }
        
        private void updateList() {
            grid.setItems(livreService.findAll(filterText.getValue()));
        }
            
   
}
```

---

and LivreForm is this:

---

```
package com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Key;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.formlayout.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.EmailField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BeanValidationBinder;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.ValidationException;
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Livre;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Livre.Categorie;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Campus;
import com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.backend.entity.Stock;

import java.util.List;

public class LivreForm extends FormLayout{
    TextField titreLivre = new TextField("titreLivre");
    TextField description = new TextField("description");
    TextField auteur = new TextField("auteur");
    TextField refeni = new TextField("refeni");
    TextField isbn = new TextField("isbn");
    ComboBox<Livre.Categorie> categorie = new ComboBox<>("Categorie");
    ComboBox<Livre.Status> status = new ComboBox<>("Status");
    ComboBox<Stock> stock = new ComboBox<>("Stock");
    ComboBox<Campus> campus = new ComboBox<>("Campus");
    
    Button save = new Button("Save"); 
    Button delete = new Button("Delete");
    Button close = new Button("Cancel");
    Binder<Livre> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Livre.class);
    private Livre livre;
    
    public LivreForm(List<Campus> campuses) {
        addClassName("livre-form");
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        campus.setItems(campuses);
        campus.setItemLabelGenerator(Campus::getNomCampus);
        status.setItems(Livre.Status.values());
        categorie.setItems(Livre.Categorie.values());
        add(titreLivre,
            description,
            auteur,
            refeni,
            isbn,
            categorie,
            status,
            campus,
            stock,
            createButtonsLayout()); 
      }
    
    public void setLivre(Livre livre) {
        this.livre = livre; 
        binder.readBean(livre); 
    }
    
    
    
    
    private Component createButtonsLayout() {
        save.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY); 
        delete.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR);
        close.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);

        save.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER); 
        close.addClickShortcut(Key.ESCAPE);
        
        save.addClickListener(event -> validateAndSave()); 
        delete.addClickListener(event -> fireEvent(new DeleteEvent(this, livre))); 
        close.addClickListener(event -> fireEvent(new CloseEvent(this))); 
        
        binder.addStatusChangeListener(e -> save.setEnabled(binder.isValid()));

        return new HorizontalLayout(save, delete, close); 
      }
    
    private void validateAndSave() {
          try {
            binder.writeBean(livre); 
            fireEvent(new SaveEvent(this, livre)); 
          } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    
    public static abstract class LivreFormEvent extends ComponentEvent<LivreForm> {
          

        private Livre livre;

          protected LivreFormEvent(LivreForm source,Livre contact) { 
            super(source, false);
            this.livre = livre;
          }

          public Livre getLivre() {
            return livre;
          }
        }

        public static class SaveEvent extends LivreFormEvent {
          SaveEvent(LivreForm source, Livre livre) {
            super(source, livre);
          }
        }

        public static class DeleteEvent extends LivreFormEvent {
          DeleteEvent(LivreForm source, Livre livre) {
            super(source, livre);
          }

        }

        public static class CloseEvent extends LivreFormEvent {
          CloseEvent(LivreForm source) {
            super(source, null);
          }
        }

        public <T extends ComponentEvent<?>> Registration addListener(Class<T> eventType,
            ComponentEventListener<T> listener) { 
          return getEventBus().addListener(eventType, listener);
        }
    

}
```

---

Hopefully, you'll tell me how line 63 and 44 are related and what's bugging them, because this particular code monkey is stumped.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `form1` isn't initialized when you try to add it on line 62.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Component to add cannot be null
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.HasComponents.add(HasComponents.java:53)
    at com.vaadin.tutorial.crm.UI.views.list.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:62)
```

Comment: Sir, you are a rockstar, as you can see, I am asomewhat inadequate admirer of your work (at 33, I came quite late to the coding game). To not consider it beneath you to answer obvious questions by lowly newbs such as myself, you a credit to your profession (as if you need me to tell you that), your framework's elegance speaks for itself,

Answer (score 1):

Use this link, it provides the optimal solution https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms#datamodel.forms.conversion